# Alternate definition of differentability at a point

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

Usually in most introductory Calculus courses, a definition of differentiability at a point $a$ is defined, as follows :

> A function $f$ is differentiable at $a$ if $f'(a)$ exists

As a corollary of this :

> A function $f$ is not differentiable at $a$ if $f'(a)$ does not exist

---

However can differentiability be defined another way, in terms of continuity of the derivative function?

***Possible* Alternate Definition**

> A function $f$ is differentiable at $a$ if $f'(x)$ is continuous at $a$

Stated more formally, given $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, $f$ is differentiable $\text{iff}$

$$\lim_{x\to a} f'(x) = f'(a)$$

---

A simple example to illustrate this would be to look at $f(x) = |x|$.

$$f'(x) =\begin{cases}
\ \ \ 1  &\text{if} & x > 0 \\
-1  &\text{if} & x < 0 \\
\end{cases}$$

And using the alternate definition, we can show that since the limit doesn't exist $$\lim_{x \to 0} f'(x) \not= f'(0)$$
 and thus $f'(x)$ is discontinous at $x=0$, and hence not differentiable at $x=0$.

---

*Note:* I haven't looked up whether this is actually a definition or not (this is just something I thought up), as far as I know, differentiability in most textbooks are *not* defined in this way. If this possible alternate definition, that I've given is incorrect, in any way whatsoever, or if it doesn't generalize well *(conceptually that is)* outside of single-variable calculus for real-valued functions, please feel free to tear it apart completely.

Comment: There exists an everywhere differentiable function whose derivative is discontinuous. Your notion is almost the same as what mathematians call $C^1$ functions (continuously differentiable functions).

Comment: So you want to say the existence of $f'(x)$ is different from saying $f$ is differentiable at $x?$ I fail to see the point of this.

Comment: @Perturbative: Wait, did you just wrote down that $f'(0)=1$ when $f(x)=|x|$?

Comment: @Mathematician42, My bad, made an error when I was typing the post out. It has been fixed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are functions which are differentiable at a point $a$ but the derivative $f'(x)$ is not continuous at $a$.  For instance, $f(x) = x^2 \cos(1/x)$ when $x\neq0$, and $f(0) = 0$.  Using the definition:
$$
    f'(0) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h}
    = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{h^2\cos(1/h)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0}h \cos(1/h) = 0
$$
(the limit is zero because the $\cos(1/h)$ term is bounded by $1$ in absolute value).
However, away from zero,
$$
    f'(x) = 2x \cos(1/x) - \sin(1/x)
$$
As $x\to 0$, the first term tends to zero but the second has no limit.  Therefore $\lim_{x\to 0} f'(x)$ does not exist.

However, if both $\lim_{x\to a^+} f'(x)$ and $f'(a)$ exist, they must agree.  Proof: For any $x$ sufficiently near $a$ but greater than $a$, the difference quotient $\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$ is equal to $f'(c_x)$ for some point $c_x$ in $(a,x)$ (Mean Value Theorem).  As $x\to a^+$, $c_x \to a$, so $f'(a) = \lim_{x\to a} f'(x)$.

Similarly, if $\lim_{x\to a^-} f'(x)$ and $f'(a)$ exist, they must agree. The proof is identical, *mutatis mutandis*.

This means that if $\lim_{x\to a^+} f'(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to a^-} f'(x)$ exist, but *disagree*, then $f$ is not differentiable at $a$.  For it it were, $f'(a)$ would need to be equal to two unequal things.

Therefore, your proof that $|x|$ is not differentiable at $0$ is legitimate, but it relies on the Mean Value Theorem rather than the definition.